# Adobe Air - Injecting javascript to popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, air, cross-domain

I am opening a URL in new window .

Like :

```
var win = window.open("http://google.com") ;
```

I want to somehow access the DOM of the opened document in that popup .

Is it possible to inject JS cross-domain ?.

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because of security issues. for detailed information, see at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f08.html